# Help with determining trigonometric limit

Tags: calculus, limits

> Use the relation $\lim_{\theta \to 0}\frac{\textrm{sin}\theta}{\theta}=1$ to determine the limit of $f(x)=\frac{\textrm{tan}(2x)}{x}$

I understand the identity $\textrm{tan}(2x)=\frac{\textrm{sin}(2x)}{\textrm{cos}(2x)}$.

So, $$\frac{\textrm{tan}(2x)}{x} = \frac{\frac{\textrm{sin}(2x)}{\textrm{cos}(2x)}}{x},$$

But then I don't understand this manipulation: $$(\frac{2}{2})   \frac{\frac{\textrm{sin}(2x)}{\textrm{cos}(2x)}}{x} = 2 (\frac{\textrm{sin}(2x)}{2x})(\frac{1}{\textrm{cos}(2x)})$$

Can you please show some in-between steps on how they arrived at this manipulation? I'm really not seeing how it works. Thank you.

Comment: The reason for multiplying by the "clever form of 1" is to get a limit we are familiar with. We know what $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{\sin x}{x}$ is. We don't immediately know what $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{\sin(2x)}{x}$ is, but if we throw a $2$ in the denominator, it's not hard to see that it'll be the same as the limit of $\frac{\sin x}{x}$ as $x\rightarrow 0$.

Comment: @CameronWilliams But why do we multiply by $(\frac{2}{2})$?

Comment: Well we want a factor of two in the denominator, but we can't do that unless we have a two in the numerator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

${\tan 2x\over x}={1\over x}\times{\sin 2x\over \cos 2x}={\sin 2x\over 2x}\times{2\over \cos 2x}$

Now take $y=2x$ so $y\to 0$ as $x\to 0$ right?

so puting $y=2x$ in above expression  and taking limit $y\to 0$ we get

$$\lim_{y\to 0}{\sin y\over y}\times {2\over \cos y}=1\times {2\over 1}=2$$